# C++ Stack implemented as an array, program crash

Tags: c++, stack

I am following the book Data Structures Using C++, 2nd Edition, D.S Malik and in the book a stack(ADT) is implemented as an array (page 400). I followed the code exactly but when I try to call .push() the program crashes; all other member functions execute without error. Any idea why it is crashing? Code below:

The abstract class:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class stackADT
{
public:
    virtual void initialiseStack() = 0;
    virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;
    virtual bool isFull() const = 0;
    virtual void push(const T& newItem) = 0;
    virtual T top() const = 0;
    virtual void pop() = 0;
};
```

StackType class definition:
(in the book definitions and implementation are placed in one .h file)

```
#ifndef STACKTYPE_H
#define STACKTYPE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

#include "StackADT.h"

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class stackType: public stackADT<T>
{
public:
    const stackType<T>& operator=(const stackType&); //
    void initialiseStack(); // initialises stack to size of 100
    bool isEmpty() const;
    bool isFull() const;
    void push(const T& newItem);
    T top() const;
    void pop();
    stackType(int stackSize = 100);
    stackType(const stackType<T>& otherStack);
    ~stackType();
    void update(T t);
    int getStackTop() const;
private:
    int maxStackSize; //holds max num of elements in stack
    int stackTop;    //holds num of elements in stack
    T *list;        //pointer to the array holding stack elements
    void copyStack(const stackType<T>& otherStack);
};
```

StackType Implementation:

```
template <class T>
void stackType<T>::initialiseStack()
{
   stackTop = 100;
}

template <class T>
bool stackType<T>::isEmpty() const
{
    return(stackTop == 0);
}

template <class T>
bool stackType<T>::isFull() const
{
    return(stackTop == maxStackSize);
}

template <class T>
void stackType<T>::push(const T& item)
{
    if(!isFull())
    {
       list[stackTop] = item;
       stackTop++;
    }
    else
        cout << "Stack is full." << endl;
}

template <class T>
T stackType<T>::top() const
{
    assert(stackTop != 0);

    return (list[stackTop - 1]);
}

template <class T>
void stackType<T>::pop()
{
    stackTop--;
}

template <class T>
void stackType<T>::copyStack(const stackType<T>& otherStack)
{
    delete [] list;
    maxStackSize = otherStack.maxStackSize;
    stackTop = otherStack.stackTop;

    list = new T[maxStackSize];

    for(int i = 0; i < stackTop; i++)
    {
        list[i] = otherStack.list[i];
    }
}

template <class T>
stackType<T>::stackType(int stackSize)
{
    if(stackSize <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Size must be positive. Creating array of size 100" << endl;
        maxStackSize = 100;
    }
    else
    {
        maxStackSize = stackSize;
    }
}

template <class T>
stackType<T>::~stackType()
{
    delete [] list;
}

template <class T>
stackType<T>::stackType(const stackType<T>& otherStack)
{
    list = NULL;

    copyStack(otherStack);
}


template <class T>
void stackType<T>::update(T t)
{
    stackType tempStack(5);
    int i = 0;
    T itemFound;

    while(!isEmpty())
    {
        if(top() != t)
        {
            tempStack.list[i] = top();
            pop();
        }
        else
        {
            itemFound = stackTop - 1;
            pop();
        }
        i++;
    }

    i = 0;

    while( i < 4)
    {
        list[i] = tempStack.top();
        tempStack.pop();
        i++;
    }

    this->push(itemFound);

}

template <class T>
int stackType<T>::getStackTop() const
{
    return stackTop;
}

template <class T>
const stackType<T>& stackType<T>::operator=(const stackType<T>& otherStack)
{
    if(this != &otherStack)
        copyStack(otherStack);

    return *this;
}

#endif // STACKTYPE_H
```

Comment: What is a "crash"? Post your exception type, message and stack trace

Comment: Where is implementation of 'initialiseStack'. The one you wrote here is just virtual function.

Plus, where do you initialize other variables? Is that all of the code? If yes, then you will have multiple null pointers..!

Comment: @Epig
 how did you initialize list?

Comment: How does it crash? `throw`s uncaught exception? Trigger CPU fault? Can you run it in a debugger to see where it crashes?

Comment: Other than that, how is `list` initialized? Is enough memory reserved for it? If it is `NULL` it would crash at `list[stackTop] = newItem`, but no other method should look in the array before first `push` has completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list` doesn't seem to be initialized - resulting in a `NULL` pointer. The constructor should be something like:

```
template <class T>
stackType<T>::stackType(int stackSize)
{
    if(stackSize <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Size must be positive. Creating array of size 100" << endl;
        maxStackSize = 100;
    }
    else
    {
        maxStackSize = stackSize;
    }

    list = new T[maxStackSize];  // <<<< initialize list
}
```

Comment: Thank you @skyking, this is what I was missing. I added the list initialisation and the program had no issues. I apologise for a seemingly dumb question but I am still learning. Thanks